# Suffix to a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to append a suffix to a variable in order to create a path in Powershell. 
Let me clarify. My $workingDirectory variable contains the path C:\temp. However, I would like to use the New-Item command to create an item in that path. My item has to be called temp.csv. The full path would be C:\temp\temp.csv.

```
New-Item $workingDirectory\temp.csv -type file
```

would however not work. I am most likely overseeing some basic syntax rule?

Does anybody know how to fix my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your path in quotes for it to work.

```
  New-Item "$workingDirectory\temp.csv" -type file
```

You can find out more about escaping characters by typing this command in the powershell console window

```
PS C:\> Help about_escaping_characters
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, now when I fill in C:\temp as the value for $workinDirectory, the file gets placed in the root of C:\? Edit:

Nevermind. My error.

Comment: please add more code to the question. Do a Write-host $workingdirectory see its contents?

Comment: I made the mistake to only define the variable within a function. Made it a $script:workingDirectory now. Seems to fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: Also note Join-Path as an alternative to joining two strings. (Join-Path $workingDirectory 'temp.csv')